# how to start a countdown timer from 1 controller and displayed in the other-angularjs

Tags: angularjs

the timer in this code is started when the program starts, that too when we set a static value in second controller.

can anyone suggest me how i can start the timer when the button in the first controller(readycntrl) is pressed and the value of the timer is dynamicaly taken from a php page(timer.ajax) and displayed in the second controller(questcntrl) in the timer tag

here is the service

```
var demoModule = angular.module('demoModule', []);

demoModule.factory('mySharedService', function($rootScope) {
    var sharedService = {};

    sharedService.sharedmessage  = '';

    sharedService.prepForPublish = function(response) {//get the value
        this.sharedmessage  = response;
        this.publishItem();
    };

    sharedService.publishItem = function() {           //$broadcast the value
        $rootScope.$broadcast('handlePublish');
    };

    return sharedService;
});
```

now these are the controllers

```
//controller which sends response to service
function ready cntrl($scope,$http,sharedService) {
    $scope.readyclick = function() {
        $scope.current= 'x';
        $scope.total= '';
        $scope.inpu= '';
        alert($scope.current);
        $http({
            method : "post",
            url    : 'fourth-submit-ajax.php',
            data   : $.param({'current':$scope.current ,
                              'total'  :$scope.total,
                              'input'  :$scope.input}),
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        }).success(function(response){
            $scope.ga=response;
            sharedService.prepForPublish(response);
        });
    }
}
```

when `readyclick` button(`readycntrl` controller) is pressed the timer should start in `questcntrl` controller and should not be started by any other things.

```
//second controller which accepts it
function questcntrl($scope,sharedService) {
    $scope.$on('handlePublish', function() {
        $scope.sharedmessage=sharedService.sharedmessage ;
    });

    $scope.startTimer = function (){
        $http.get('timer-ajax.php').success(function(response) {
            // this is the value of timer dynamically coming from timer.php
            $scope.wow = response[0].time;
        }); 
        $scope.$broadcast('timer-set-countdown');
        $scope.$broadcast('timer-start');

        $scope.timerRunning = true;
    };

    $scope.stopTimer = function (){
        $scope.$broadcast('timer-stop');
        $scope.timerRunning = false;
    };

    $scope.$on('timer-stopped', function (event, data){
        console.log('Timer Stopped - data = ', data);
    });
}
```

now these are the dependency injection for service

```
readycntrl.$inject = ['$scope', 'mySharedService'];        
questcntrl.$inject = ['$scope', 'mySharedService'];
```

the html code:

```
<div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <div ng-controller="readycntrl">
       <table align="center">
            <tr>
                <td><p>Are You Ready ?</p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><a href="" data-transition="flow" class="…" ng-click="readyclick()">start</a></td>
                <td><a href="#secall" data-transition="turn" class="…">back</a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

the countdown value is a variable(wow) present in questcnrtl controller

```
<div ng-controller="questcntrl">
    {{sharedmessage}}
    <timer countdown="wow" interval="1000" finish-callback="askstart(current,total,inpu); startTimer();">{{countdown}}{{}}</timer>
</div>
```

timer-ajax.php only contains the value 30 (dynamically coming from php)
there is another timer.js file which is used for this which is common

somebody please help me out here....

Comment: That HTML seems broken you never close the table and start a div inbetween rows

Comment: sorry  just minims ed the codes for easy viewing ,should i put the entire code?

Comment: should be  : `readycntrl.$inject = ['$scope','$http' 'mySharedService'];`

Comment: in the `readycntrl` you seem to pass `$scope.inpu` to the `fourth-submit-ajax.php`. please check if the **t** was lost while copy-pasting or is it a typo in your code. in `questcntrl::startTimer` please check if `response` is actually a JSON object and the `vava` value is set correctly. also please create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with your code so far, so the community has a better starting point. I also can't see where you define the `timer` directive

Answer (score 0):

you have to refer the service in to the controller in order to use it in your controller.

```
function readycntrl($scope,$http, 'mySharedService') {
```

Comment: when we put sharedService along with $http, the http part is not working.

Answer (score 0):

thanks @MiTa now i have the solution for problem

we need to add the $http into the dependency injection part solves the issue

```
readycntrl.$inject = ['$scope','$http','mySharedService'];
```

adding this to the code solves the problem 
once again thanks @MiTa
thanks everyone

Comment: i am sorry that i have modified this question,because the code is too big