# how to start a countdown timer from 1 controller and displayed in the other-angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-mobile, timer

i am sorry to say that the code is too big so i have modified my previous question into the code .
pardon me.

this is the link for that

[how to start a countdown timer from 1 controller and displayed in the other-angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25665117/how-to-start-a-countdown-timer-from-1-controller-and-displayed-in-the-other-angu)

the timer in this code is started when the program starts, that too when we set a static value in second controller.

can anyone suggest me how i can start the timer when the button in the first controller(readycntrl) is pressed and the value of the timer is dynamicaly taken from a php page(timer.ajax) and displayed in the second controller(questcntrl) in the timer tag.

```
<timer countdown="wow" interval="1000" finish-callback="askstart(current,total,inpu); startTimer();">{{countdown}}{{}}</timer>
```

please refer to the above link to see the question..

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to start a countdown timer from 1 controller and displayed in the other-angularjs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25665117/how-to-start-a-countdown-timer-from-1-controller-and-displayed-in-the-other-angu)

Comment: pardon me that was also posted by me..

Comment: that is why i have given the reference...

Comment: that other post have the same title and question and **was not yet answered** in a way you could accept it. Please don't double post as a matter of giving your question attention. This practice is not well received and will result in duplicates deletion and if very often used in other consequences such as warnings or bans.

Comment: am sorry it was an emergency situation i will remove it as soon as possible

Answer (score 0):

Try to use angular events

readycntrl

```
$scope.click = function(){
   $rootScope.$broadcast("button_clicked");
}
```

questcntrl

```
$scope.$on("button_clicked", function(){
   $scope.timerStart(VAR_FROM_PHP);
})
```

in timer direcitive

```
{
  scope: {start: '='},
  link: function(scope){
   scope.start = function(start_time){
      // starting timer
   }
 }
}
```

in html

```
<timer start="timerStart" ... />
```